# How to fetch data for eloqua campaigns using API

Tags: oracle, rest, eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

I was trying to fetch the data from eloqua API for campaigns, but I was only able to fetch the fields and not the data. Can anyone help me on how to fetch the data using API for campaigns?

Used both bulk and rest API URL but was unable to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

These endpoints can be used to retrieve campaigns:

- [Retrieve a list of campaigns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-rest-api/op-api-rest-2.0-assets-campaigns-get.html)
- [Retrieve a campaign](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-rest-api/op-api-rest-2.0-assets-campaign-id-get.html)